# How can I "check/uncheck" nodes "child/parent" independently in JSTree?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I need that the parents and children nodes can be checked independently. For instance, if my tree has one node with child, the comportment is:

If I check this child, automatically the parent will be checked too, or vice versa.
I wanna can check a child or parent and do not change the other.

How can I "remove" this dependency of both?

Any help is appreciated.

Thank advance!

Comment: Can we what you've done so far? Like some code.

Comment: hi @dcodesmith, I solved my question putting the option "two_state" : true.. thanks =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the answer for my question in own jstree site:

[link](http://www.jstree.com/documentation/checkbox)

> two_state
>   A boolean. Default is false.
>   If set to true checkboxes will be two-state only, meaning that you will be able to select parent and children independently and there will be no undetermined state.

So, I solved my question putting the option below:

```
"checkbox" : { 
    "two_state" : true
}
```

Att

Comment: The current version of the jstree api doesn't use two_state, the correct option is three_state and defaults to true so you would need to set it to false http://www.jstree.com/api/#/?q=$.jstree.defaults.checkbox&f=$.jstree.defaults.checkbox.three_state

Comment: Hi, thanks. I agree it's old(ish) but I had the same issue and Google led me straight here so I guess it's in order to keep it up to date for others.